# Are there language immersion courses in Austria?

Tags: austria, language

I've seen [this question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/123/language-immersion-courses-in-the-usa) and I'm wondering the same for a different country: Austria.
I would like to do a course of German A1 or a course of English B2.

Can you advice me how to take courses in the evening?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would look for the nearest VHS (Volkshochschule). They normally offer language courses and also offer proficiency testing.

Since you are living in Innsbruck, the natural choice would be the local branch of the [Volkshochschule Tirol](http://www.vhs-tirol.at/page.cfm?vpath=kurse&fachbereichId=183). They offer a lot of courses for German as a foreign language, many of which are in the evening. They also offer courses through level C1 for [English](http://www.vhs-tirol.at/page.cfm?vpath=kurse&fachbereichId=4).

[Here](http://www.vhs-tirol.at/page.cfm?vpath=ueber-uns/zweigstelle&zid=218&tuwasid=2200) is the contact page for the one in Innsbruck. They may be able to provide assistance in booking the course over telephone if you have trouble navigating the site.

Comment: I'm living in Innsbruck. I can go only in the evening.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an [Italian website](http://scappiamo.net/imparare-il-tedesco-in-austria/), which talks about some language schools, including:

- http://www.bfi.at/kurse/fachbereiche/sprachen
- http://www.wifi.at/DE/Kursbuch/Sprachen/Sprachen.aspx
- http://www.vhs.at/12719.html
- http://sprachenzentrum.univie.ac.at/content/site/spzuw/en/home/index.html
- http://germanistik.univie.ac.at/
- http://dante.at/